# Como deixar um rodapé fixo no layout do Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Tenho o seguinte layout em **xml** no meu designer Android:

[image: Designer do Layout de Configurações]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ativar Notificações:" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Inativo"
                android:id="@+id/checkAtivarNotificacao" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tempo em Minutos das Notificações:"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none|number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/txtIntervaloNotificacao"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Salvar"
        android:id="@+id/btSalvarConfiguracao" />

</LinearLayout>
```

O problema é que de acordo com o que eu eu vou adicionando componentes na tela e o ScrollView vai descendo o **botão de salvar** desaparece, sendo assim eu quero deixar um espaço de rodapé com o botão salvar fixo e o conteúdo do layout flexível independente do quanto aumente, exatamente como acontece no aplicativo padrão de mensagens do android ilustrado abaixo:

[image: Layout Android com Rodapé Fixo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria interessante vc colocar seu `xml`, para sabermos identificar onde errou. Mas como a pergunta é meio genérica, eis a minha resposta:

Utilize `RelativeLayout`. O que você desejar centralizar dentro dele você utilize alguma propriedade dele de centralização:

1. `centerInParent` - Centraliza no meio(horizontalmente e verticalmente) do `RelativeLayout`.
2. `centerHorizontal` - Centraliza horizontalmente, em relação ao `RelativeLayout`
3. `centerVertical` - Centraliza verticalmente, em relação ao `RelativeLayout`

Exemplo de código:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**// EDIT**

Com sua melhor especificação na pergunta, te repito, montar um layout do android cada um tem seu jeito, e possuem várias formas de fazer a mesma coisa.

No seu caso eu simplesmente colocaria todo esse codigo dentro de um `LinearLayout` e atribuiria a propriedade `layout_weight=1` no `ScrollView`.

Segue código:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ativar Notificações:" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Inativo"
                android:id="@+id/checkAtivarNotificacao" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tempo em Minutos das Notificações:"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none|number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/txtIntervaloNotificacao"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Salvar"
            android:id="@+id/btSalvarConfiguracao"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hugo Fagundes eu reformulei a questão, talvez agora fique mais clara, obrigado!

Comment: Pronto, editei minha resposta, dá uma olhada ;)